# Require input password if session idle

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, session-timeout

in my application, there is a login page to validate user account and password.

There will be enhancement that if user click on some confidential page such as Salary, Personal details, etc. it will redirect to a page to input password again.

As to avoid user input password for each confidential page, i want to create a session when user 1st time to click on confidential page and input correct password. if idle time less than 5 minutes, they don't need to input password again even though click on other confidential page. otherwise, if the pc idle more than 5 minutes, it will redirect to password page...

How can i create session for the above approach ?

in the web.config, it already have session timeout for the whole applications

```
<system.web>  
<sessionState timeout="240"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

Can I assign another sessionstate for this approach ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend storing a timestamp on the `Session` value itself, like this:

```
Session("ConfidentialPageAccess") = DateTime.Now
```

Then when you want to check the `Session` value, you can compare the value stored against "now" minus 5 minutes, like this:

```
Dim dateConfidentialPageAccess = TryCast(Session("ConfidentialPageAccess"), DateTime)

If (dateConfidentialPageAccess - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes > 5 Then
    ' Redirect to login page
End If
```